# Bijection between subsets of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H \subset G$ a subgroup. For a $k \in G$, I have to find a bijection between the sets $A := \{g \in G\, |\, k^{-1}gk \in  H\}$ and $B:= kHk^{-1}$.

They very clearly seem somewhat related, but I have no idea on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just $$k^{-1}gk=h\Leftrightarrow g=khk^{-1}$$ and assume $g\mapsto h$

Comment: I knew it had to be something really easy... Thanks!

Comment: @Francesco Carzaniga You are welcome!